# What is the perfect way to compare Excel column and extract the common data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, python, r

I have 4 columns in Excel file. I want to compare col1 with col3 and extract the common item along with col2 and col4, like in the image below. I am familiar with basic R and Python and basic Linux command line.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*You need an Array (CSE) Formula:*

[image]

- Formula in cell A84:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(A$80:A$82, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(C$80:C$82, A$80:A$82), MATCH(ROW(A$80:A$82),ROW(A$80:A$82)), ""), ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill across.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

*Additionally, if you are working with higher version then you may use,*

```
=FILTER(list1,COUNTIF(list2,list1))
```

Comment: Glad to help you @Taufiq ,, keep asking ☺

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Thank you. I have done it but I got only the common value but did not get the  number as you get here like for b, 1 and 2. https://prnt.sc/z26lzo

Comment: Drag the formula RIGHT the DOWN is in A84, after you finish with Ctrl+Shift+Enter  you get it .

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.